# R – How to create a function that matches a string and then creates new variable from it?

Tags: r, regex, string, function, vector

I have a variable called "codes".

```
codes <- c("N011", "H002", NA, NA, "D001", NA, "N011")
```

I would like to create a function where the arguments are any part of the character strings in codes, for example: `"N01"` or `"H"`, so the function identifies those that match and assigns a number to each on a separate variable. In this case, with arguments `"N01"` and `"H"`, I would like the new variable to be something like this:

```
new_variable
1
2
0
0
0
0
1
```

I created a function capable of doing this with a single argument, but I haven't been able to create one with *n* number of arguments:

```
fun <- function(x, codes) {
  mutate(data, new_variable = ifelse(grepl(x, codes, fixed = TRUE), 1, 0))
}

fun("N001", codes)
new_variable
1
0
0
0
0
0
1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(stringr)

codes <- c("N011", "H002", NA, NA, "D001", NA, "N012")

to_find <- c("N01", "H")

find <- function(to_find, x) {
  res <- vector("integer", length(x))
  for (i in seq_along(to_find)) {
    res[str_detect(x, to_find[i])] <- i
  }
  res
}

find(to_find, codes)
```

Comment: Very concise! But this one looks for "exact matches" right? So if we change the last item to "N012" this function brings us "0" instead of "1". For that issue is there any better approach than `grepl` which he's been using?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the best approach but you can do a nested `ifelse` (or its Tidyverse form `if_else`) and just add on to your conditions. Basically when the initial condition fails those items are passed to the secondary ifelse statement and so on:

```
codes <- c("N011", "H002", NA, NA, "D001", NA, "N011")

newVar = dplyr::if_else(grepl("N", codes, fixed = T), 1,
                 if_else(grepl("H", codes, fixed = T), 2, 0))
```